# Searching through DataGridView Using TextBox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to be able to search through my Datagridview using Textbox. The code below has worked fine before. But presently it is searching only for items under column 'category' whereas it is supposed to search through all the other columns too.

```
Public Sub loaddata()
' This loads data into the datagridview
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\inventory1.accdb")
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = "SELECT product_cat as category, product_name as ProductName, product_desc as ProductDesc, cost_price as CostPrice, sales_price as SalesPrice FROM tblproducts"
        End With

        Dim das = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        das.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim dt = New DataTable
        das.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub txtfilter_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtfilter.TextChanged
    Try
        loaddata()
        DataGridView2.DataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[ProductName] LIKE '%{0}%'", txtfilter.Text)
        DataGridView2.DataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[ProductDesc] LIKE '%{0}%'", txtfilter.Text)
        DataGridView2.DataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[category] LIKE '%{0}%'", txtfilter.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataGridView2.DataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[ProductName] LIKE '%{0}%' OR [ProductDesc] LIKE '%{0}%' OR [category] LIKE '%{0}%'", txtfilter.Text)
```

The way you're currently doing it, only the last filter will be used, because you replace it every time you try to "add" a filter.

I assumed your query was a `OR`, but just change the `OR` for an `AND` if that's what you need.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like bomb.But this method could not be used for integers or double. Any heads up?

Comment: @mantics Well, it's not going to work if you are using the LIKE comparison.  If you want help, you will have to provide more information than "it doesn't work".

Comment: @LarsTech, the datagrid been referenced has some fields that are integers like CostPrice. I want to make use of a single Textbox to check for availability of the CostPrice which is an integer/double as well as the Productname that is a String

Comment: If only one of your columns is an Integer, like an ID for example, use two different parameters => `{0} / {1}`, one of which would be the integer version of what you're looking for. Use the right parameter for the right column.

Comment: @larstech, still using the String.Format?

Comment: @mantics yes, but your sql string won't have those single quotes around the {0} data entry.